# Java Recursive Merge Sort

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

Currently am struck on my recursive merge sorting program, I have been looking to see where the problem is and i cant seem to find it.

```
package mergesort;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MergeSort {

public MergeSort() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void mergesort(T[] list, int n)
{
    mergeSort(list,0,n-1);
}

static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
void mergeSort(T[] tempArray, int firstHalfSorted, int secondHalfSorted){
    T[] temp = (T[]) new Comparable <?>[tempArray.length];
    mergeSort(tempArray, temp, firstHalfSorted, secondHalfSorted);

}


private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
void mergeSort (T[ ] tempArray, T[] a, int firstHalfSorted, int secondHalfSorted){
    if (firstHalfSorted < secondHalfSorted)
    {
        int mid =   (firstHalfSorted + secondHalfSorted) / 2;
        mergeSort(tempArray,a,firstHalfSorted, mid);
        mergeSort(tempArray,a,mid+1, secondHalfSorted);
        if(tempArray[mid].compareTo(tempArray[mid+1])>0)
            merge(tempArray,a,firstHalfSorted, mid, secondHalfSorted);
    }
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> 
void merge(T[] a, T[] tempArray, int firstHalfSorted, int mid, int secondHalfSorted)
{
    int bhalf1 = firstHalfSorted;
    int ehalf1 = mid;
    int bhalf2 = mid + 1;
    int ehalf2 = secondHalfSorted;
    int j = 0;
    for(;(bhalf1 <= ehalf1) && (bhalf2 <= ehalf2); j++)
    {
        if (a[bhalf1].compareTo(a[bhalf2]) < 0)
        {
            tempArray[j] = a[bhalf1];   
            bhalf1++;
        }
        else 
        {
            tempArray[j] = a[bhalf2];
            bhalf2++;

        }

    for(;bhalf1 <= ehalf1; bhalf2++, j++)
        tempArray[j] = a[bhalf1];   
    for(;bhalf2 <= ehalf2; bhalf2++, j++)
        tempArray[j] = a[bhalf2];   
    for(j = firstHalfSorted; j <= secondHalfSorted; j++)
        a[j] = tempArray[j];
    }
}

}
```

here is the sample of what should be happening

Before sort:
Zeke
Bob
Ali
John
Jody
Jamie
Bill
Rob
Zeke
Clayton

After sort:
Ali
Bill
Bob
Clayton
Jamie
Jody
John
Rob
Zeke
Zeke

also my main driver i made is here also

```
package mergesort;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Driver <T extends Comparable<? super T>>{

public Driver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static <T> void main(String[] args) {

       String array[] = new String[] {"Zeke,"Bob","Ali","John","Jody","Jamie","Bill","Rob", "Zeke", "Clayton"};
    MergeSort sortList = null;
    sortList.mergeSort(array,0,10);
    for(int a=0;a<array.length;a++)
        System.out.println(array[a]);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: You should make a print for every iteration, that would help you to see what is really going on

Comment: @Ajoy "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
 at mergesort.MergeSort.merge(MergeSort.java:59)
 at mergesort.MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:32)
 at mergesort.MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:29)
 at mergesort.MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:29)
 at mergesort.MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:29)
 at mergesort.MergeSort.mergeSort(MergeSort.java:19)
 at mergesort.Driver.main(Driver.java:15)
"

Answer (score 1):

Your `merge` method has many problems.

1. Take every `for` loop in there and write a 1-line comment describing what it's supposed to do.
2. Do **not** declare a variable (like `j`) and then reuse it for multiple loops.  Confine the loop variable to the loop scope, e.g. `for (int j = ..; .. ; ..)`.
3. Correct your indentation and make sure that the nested loops were really meant to be nested.
4. Write a few test cases for `merge` method and test just that method separately from all the recursion.